# File uploading using ajax and Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to upload file using ajax and Laravel so the ajax is working fine I can see it's passing data and from the back-end side Laravel is getting data, storing into the database but I believe something is wrong from ajax or maybe from storing side because after upload when I try to use the uploaded file it shows that it's corrupted. Below is my code:

**HTML CODE**

```
<form id="mediaForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
<input type="hidden" name="to" name="to" value="{{$user->id}}" />
<input type="file" name="chat_file" id="chat_file" />
</form>
```

**AJAX CALL**

```
$("#chat_file").change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var formID = $("#mediaForm");
    var formData = new FormData(formID[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/request/send-media-message',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {
            if(response == '1'){
            getMessages();
            } else {
                alert(response);
            }
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

and on the backend side the Laravel code looks like below:

```
if($ReqType == 'send-media-message'){
if(preg_match("/\.(gif|png|jpg|jfif|jpeg)$/", $_FILES['chat_file']['name'])){
$filename = $_FILES['chat_file']['name'];
$photofilecontent = file_get_contents($_FILES["chat_file"]["tmp_name"]);
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['chat_file']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg'){ $mimetype = 'image/jpeg'; } else if($ext == 'png'){ $mimetype = 'image/png'; }
DB::table('messages')->insert([
'dated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'from_id' => Session::get('id'),
'to_id' => $request->to,
'msg' => 'media message',
'is_media' => '1',
'mimetype' => $mimetype,
'ext' => $ext,
'file_content' => $photofilecontent
]);
return 1;exit;//no need to redirect anywhere
} else {
$alerts = array('Invalid file selected');
return $alerts; exit; //no need to redirect anywhere
}
}
```

I tried multiple ways to pass form data using ajax but no luck and this is what I am getting when I am trying to use it. I am sure that I am using it correctly but I think the file is not reading properly so confused data is storing into the data base which is cause the below [screen shot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGTbW.jpg)

Comment: Which side is failing? In your browser, can you see (*developer* tools network tab) the file being sent?

Comment: yes file is being sent that's why on the Laravel side I am able to get mimetype and file extension but I belive the files content is not passing properly from ajax or maybe the way I am strong file content is wrong. I am really not sure where is the mistake happening.

Comment: OK, I'm out, as I have no clue about laravel/PHP

Comment: can you share your table migration for your messages table? - question being; is your file_content column too short or the wrong type? - you can check this by printing file_content when you store it, vs what's in the table

Comment: Also please share your code where you're reading out and passing the media back to the frontend

Comment: I got fixed it by myself. I just base64_encoded before storing to the database and it works for me.